# Xubuntu using Chrome 55 and can't apply Adobe plugin to all users (including guest)

Tags: xubuntu, google-chrome, flash

We have our computers setup with Xubuntu using chrome and a customized guest mode for students to use.  Everything has been working fine with Flash, until the upgrade to Chrome 55 (I think that's what caused it not to work).  Now when I install the `adobe-flashplugin`, it works for the user I installed it for, but not in guest mode.  I have tried changing permissions on `/home/guest-prefs/.config/google-chrome/PepperFlash` and updated the `manifest.json` file.  The guest mode does not find/use the Adobe plugin.

Any suggestions?  I have also moved the Plugin directory to `/opt/google/chrome/` and pointed the `manifest.json` file there, but no luck.  I do not have a lot of experience with Ubuntu, it just has worked for the last 18 months using the instructions I have found here.

Answer (score 1):

I created the account *guest-prefs* in accordance with [CustomizeGuestSession](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CustomizeGuestSession) and started Chrome as part of the preparations. Then I removed the `/home/guest-prefs/.config/google-chrome/PepperFlash` folder.

After that I could use Flash with Chrome in the guest session. However, I had to close and reopen Chrome once or twice before it started to work. Not ideal, but better than not working at all...

This was on Ubuntu 16.10, but I think that neither the release nor the flavor matters.

Comment: I tried your recommendation, but it still didn't work in guest mode.  Although when I look at chrome://components it indicates flash version 24 is installed and updated.  Chrome://plugins indicates the flash version 23 and chrome://flash indicates 23.0.0.185 internal not installed.  Any other suggestions?  I would hate to rebuild these images, but that is my next step if I can get this sorted out.  TIA!

Comment: @LisaS: Well, I say it works (with the reservation mentioned), you say it doesn't, and I smell some kind of misconception. You may want to try with a fresh install, install Google Chrome, launch a guest session, and open/close Chrome a couple of times. That's what I started with to find out whether the latest Chrome version works with Flash in the guest session and concluded that it does.

Comment: I rebuilt my image from scratch and can confirm that in guest mode, this will work if the student relaunches the browser a couple of times.  We'll just instruct the students about this process.  Not ideal, maybe they will find another website.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: @LisaS: Ok, good, then we see the same thing. Btw, is Chrome a must, or would Firefox work? I think FF would work without this kind of hassle.

Comment: I work in a school district and we use Google Apps for Education, so chrome is a must.  I create images with older computers using Xubuntu.  Before the kids can access the internet, they need to log in with their school Google accounts.